# Snapbridge and D500 were working with Bluetooth image transfers to my iPhone. Now not working

Tags: nikon, file-transfer, snapbridge, bluetooth

I have the Nikon D500, with the latest firmware and have not changed anything on the camera.

Snapbridge was working for image transfers between the camera and an iPhone running iOS 11. I would select the picture to send and the D500 would automatically connect to my phone and transfer the image.

I have removed the D500 from my phone and my phone from the D500 and reinstalled by going through all the steps.  I have a connection between the two and the Bluetooth icon on Snapbridge shows a connection with my phone.  It also shows if the battery on the D500 gets low.  I cannot get the pictures to transfer though through Bluetooth.  I can get them if I transfer to wifi, but I like the ease and convenience of Bluetooth.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: This seems like more of a software issue than photography?

Comment: @Matthew Subjects such as use and operation of equipment related to photography are on-topic here. It might be a software issue, but it is software specific to, and only of interest to, photography (even then, only a subset of photography: recent Nikon bodies).

Comment: It's not clear, what has changed? You updated the firmware on the D500? But you said the latest firmware didn't change anything on camera. How do you know that? Did the iPhone app get updated? Why did you unpair and re-pair the devices?

Comment: @Matthew I should probably caveat my previous comment, because it can be taken too far. For instance, Photoshop is obviously of interest to photography, but not _all_ of its use, operation, configuration, etc., is necessarily on-topic here (graphic design use, beyond a photographic context, is an obvious case where it would be off-topic). And even in the case of Snapbridge, if somebody were doing something very esoteric, unsupported by Nikon, that might become off-topic here too. But so far, it sounds like this specific question is _probably_ on-topic, at least IMO. =)

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I updated the original post.  Nothing has changed on the camera.  There could be updates on the iOS and program updates.  I unpaired and re-pair everything because files your not being transferred.  The devices were pairing but not sending images.  I don't send every image, only the ones I tag with the camera.

Comment: iOS makes its updates when it wants. It's difficult to turn it off, if at all. Do you have other BlueTooth devices close by that could be interfering with that transfer. BlueTooth is not bulletproof and can be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that hasn't been suggested is to completely delete the SnapBridge app from your phone. Re-boot your phone and then re-install the app.
It worked for me.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this page? It explains how to set up the auto-transfer. I suspect you don't have that enabled.

http://nikonimglib.com/snbr/onlinehelp/en/03_transfer_01.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi there my photography friend :) So my suggestion to you (granted this is unfortunately still a issue) would be to make sure that any bluetooth enabled devices currently connected to you Iphone are all disabled. I would recommend going to your bluetooth settings and manually "forget" all previously connected as well as all currently connected bluetooth enabled devices. After doing this make sure you keep your bluetooth enabled, now if there are any bluetooth devices (speaker,headphones,etc) around you please go ahead and make sure you power all of them off as well as the D500. After this is complete and all bluetooth devices are off now disable bluetooth on your iphone and give it a restart. As your phone is restarting turn your D500 off and right back on,then enable your cameras bluetooth once more. AT this point your iphone should be completely rebooted now enable your bluetooth on once more, now your D500 should be the only device your phone identifies. Connect to it and all should be functioning properly again.
If this doesn't work try to update your D500s firmware via the camera itself.

What a wonderful camera the D500 is!  Hey again hope this is resolved but for some reason it isnt I truly hope this works.